# How to print PDFs to a network printer

Tags: pdf, windows-server

We currently generate PDFs (mono black) to a folder then use a Windows service to print with Adobe Reader. This is not stable, and causes issues occasionally, so we are looking for a solution.

**Must have:**

- Can monitor a folder then print, *the network printer* can be specified *in run-time*, e.g. with corresponding 'meta' file or as part of the file name;
- Produces a report/dashboard for operations, e.g. which files printed to where, print result, time;
- **Very important** - robust, high throughput yet not losing any quality.

**Nice to have:**

- Able to control print quality, e.g. darkness - we found Foxit tends to print darker than Adobe somehow;
- Send alert upon error, e.g. printer out of paper, jam, door open.

Thanks in advance for help!!!

Comment: This would be so easy to do with a linux print server. I assume you don't have one of those? (If so add the Windows Tag)

Answer (score 1):

We've used File Processor ([www.fileprocessor.info](http://www.fileprocessor.info)) for similar tasks in combination with Print&Share ([www.printandshare.info](http://www.printandshare.info)).